# HTTP Post on raspberry pi fails with Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, asp.net, http, post, ntlm

I need to do HTTP POST to an ASPX page which has NTLM authentication and I am able to do that and get the response from the server. but I can do it only from a windows PC and mac. But strangely I cannot run it on Raspberry Pi because I get "**connection reset by peer**" error.(GET calls are ok and also POST with size smaller than 819 characters)
I have implemented it with Python 2, 3 and nodejs and I get same error so it is not for sure the code cause also it is running on PC and Mac.
I also tried to post the same call to my fake API server and it was successful but mine was flask without NTLM.
I'm sure that the main problem is the payload which is too big, because when I make it less that 819 characters, it return at least an error but higher than that it's not even arrive to server.

this is my payload:

```
payload = {
    'Data' : '{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}',
    'Encoded': '1',
    'IDExcelTemplate': 'STD_1',
    'IsPreview': '1',
    'Type': '1'
    }
```

also my header is:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host': '10.1.10.227',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'it-IT, it; q=0.5',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive' 
    }
```

This is my code in Python:

```
import requests
import time
import threading
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Comment
from datetime import date, timedelta , datetime
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTPException
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
import ConfigParser
import ast
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


def send_email(sender, sender_password, receiver, message):
    print("sending email...")
    try:
        mail_session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        mail_session.ehlo()
        mail_session.starttls()
        mail_session.ehlo()
        mail_session.login(sender, sender_password)           
        mail_session.sendmail(sender,receiver,message)
        mail_session.quit()
        print "Successfully sent email"
    except smtplib.SMTPException , e:
        print "Error: unable to send email" + str(e)
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print "SMTPAuthenticationError" + str(e)
    except smtplib.SMTPConnectError:
        print "SMTPConnectError" + str(e)

#Read From config.ini
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
config.sections()
sender = ast.literal_eval(config.get('general', 'sender_email'))
sender_password = ast.literal_eval(config.get('general', 'sender_password'))
receiver = ast.literal_eval(config.get('general', 'receiver_email'))
subject_ticket = ast.literal_eval(config.get('general', 'subject_email_ticket'))
subject_no_ticket = ast.literal_eval(config.get('general', 'subject_email_noticket'))
subject_error = ast.literal_eval(config.get('general', 'subject_email_error'))
username = ast.literal_eval(config.get('general', 'username'))
password = ast.literal_eval(config.get('general', 'password'))


while True:

    # Getting all tickets created
    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\\' + username, password, session)
    try:
        print("call 1")
        response = session.get('http://10.1.10.227/iwebpro/')
    except:
        print("no success")

    try:
        print("call 2")
        response = session.get('http://10.1.10.227/iwebpro/HDA/Logon/Logon.aspx')
    except:
        print("no success on LOGIN")


    payload = {
        'Data' : '{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}',
        'Encoded': '1',
        'IDExcelTemplate': 'STD_1',
        'IsPreview': '1',
        'Type': '1'
        }
    headers = {
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Host': '10.1.10.227',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'it-IT, it; q=0.5',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
        }
    try:
        print("call 3")
        response2 = session.post('http://10.1.10.227/iwebpro/HDA/Excel/ExcelPreview.aspx', data=payload, headers=headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        print("no success on POST")

    # print (response2.text)  
    #if call is not successfull
    if response2.status_code == 200 :
        # Filter tickets which is created in last x minutes
        t = response2.text
        results = {}
        bs = BeautifulSoup(t)
        results = {}
        for row in bs.findAll('tr'):
            aux = row.findAll('td')
            if str(aux[7].string) != 'None':
                d = datetime.strptime(str(aux[7].string), "%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S")
                difference = datetime.today() - d
                #print difference.days #days
                #print divmod(difference.seconds, 3600)[0] # hours
                #print divmod(difference.seconds, 60)[0] # Minutes
                if  difference.days == 0 and divmod(difference.seconds, 60)[0] <= 31:
                    results[str(aux[0].string)] = [str(d),str(aux[6].string),str(aux[2].string)]
        print results

        # Sending result as an email
        if(bool(results)):
            body = 'New Tickets have been created:\n\n'
            for x in results: 
                body = body + '   - ID ' + x + ' created on ' + results[x][0] + ' for "'+ results[x][1] + '" with subject of "'+ \
                        results[x][2] +'"\n'
            body = body + '\nBest Regards, \nAutomatic Script'
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = sender
            msg['To'] = receiver
            msg['Subject'] = str(time.time()) + subject_ticket
            msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
            message = str(msg)
            #send an email
            send_email(sender, sender_password, receiver, message)
        else:
            print "No new ticket"
            body = 'There is no new ticket'
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = sender
            msg['To'] = receiver
            msg['Subject'] = str(time.time()) + subject_no_ticket
            msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
            message = str(msg)
            send_email(sender, sender_password, receiver, message)


    time.sleep(30*60)
```

Comment: Can you share the Python code?

Comment: I've updated the post